# Can I save MSP430 CRC registers during FreeRTOS context switch?

Tags: operating-system, crc, msp430, context-switch, freertos

I am using MSP430F5418 with FreeRTOS 7 in medium data model.

I want to save the MSP CRC registers on FreeRTOS context switch.
I edited the portext.s43 like this.

In save context macro, after pushing 15 registers to stack, I push the CRC registers.
(CRCDI is the MSP register to save)

```
mov.w CRCD1, r15 
pushx.a r15
```

In restore context macro, I poped the CRC just before poping the 15 registers.

```
popx.a r15
mov.w r15, CRCDI
```

It is supposed to be working , but it is not. The program control is going to unknow location.

Anybody have any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why people ask FreeRTOS support questions on forums other than the free and active FreeRTOS support request forum.  It makes my life difficult though.

I have answered your question here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/freertos/forums/forum/382005/topic/5367023

Comment: I am sorry. I just posted everywhere to get more answers faster

Comment: Possibly because SO is a very well working and non project specific site for questions and answers, while SF is a creeping horror.